# Optimizing MySQL query with some LEFT OUTER JOINS

Tags: mysql

I have a classifieds website and want to optimize the most intensive query in my server. I don´t have so much experience with MySQL (or any other DB).

This is the complete listing ads:

```
SELECT
    `category`.`id` AS `category_id`,
    `category`.`subcat` AS `category_name`,
    `category`.`desc` AS `category_desc`,
    `category`.`name` AS `category_pretty_name`,
    `ads`.`id`,
    `ads`.`header`,
    `ads`.`price`,
    `ads`.`oldprice`,
    `ads`.`sellfast`,
    `ads`.`foto1`,
    `ads`.`subcat_id`,
    `ads`.`updated`,
    `ads`.`created`,
    `ads`.`name`,
    `ads`.`phone`,
    `ads`.`hits`,
    `rating_ad`.`num_rates` AS `num_rates`,
    `rating_ad`.`average_rating` AS `average_rating`,
    SUBSTR(ads.body, 1, 160) AS body,
    `ads`.`user_id`,
    `ads`.`hash`,
    `ads`.`hidden`,
    `ads`.`email`,
    `promo`.`promotype` AS `promo_type`,
    `promo`.`end_promo`,
    `supercategory`.`name` AS `supercategory_name`,
    `supercategory`.`id` AS `supercategory_id`
FROM
    `ads`
JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id` = `ads`.`subcat_id`
JOIN `supercategory` ON `supercategory`.`id` = `category`.`cat`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `promo` ON `promo`.`ads_id` = `ads`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ad_id,
        TRUNCATE (AVG(rating), 2) AS average_rating,
        COUNT(user_id) AS num_rates
    FROM
        ads_rating
    GROUP BY
        ad_id
    HAVING
        COUNT(user_id) >= 1
) AS rating_ad ON `rating_ad`.`ad_id` = `ads`.`id`
WHERE
    `ads`.`sellfast` = '1'
AND `ads`.`subcat_id` = '19'
AND `recycle_bin` = 0
AND `hidden` = 0
ORDER BY
    `promo_type` DESC,
    `updated` DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

When I do the EXPLAIN Query, this is the result:

[image: MySQL EXPLIN Results]

So, I see in the Slow queries logs this is consuming about 0.350 secs. Is this optimizable?

This is the SHOW CRETE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `ads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subcat_id` mediumint(2) NOT NULL,
  `province_id` mediumint(2) NOT NULL,
  `price` float(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `oldprice` float(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL,
  `header` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `body` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `public_email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `foto1` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `foto2` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `foto3` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `foto4` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `foto5` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `new` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `sellfast` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `website` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  `hidden` smallint(1) NOT NULL,
  `recycle_bin` smallint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`hash`),
  KEY `header` (`header`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tags` (`tags`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `phone` (`phone`) USING BTREE,
  KEY ` subcat_id` (`subcat_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `province_id` (`province_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `hidden` (`hidden`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `recycle_bin` (`recycle_bin`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `price` (`price`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `email` (`email`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `created` (`created`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `updated` (`updated`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `new` (`new`),
  KEY `sellfast` (`sellfast`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=839759 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Which task most do to made it?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is important for optimization to know, for example, which table `recycle_bin` is in.

Even before looking at the joins, get rid of the "index merge intersect" by building a "composite" index:

```
 INDEX(sellfast, subcat_id, recycle_bin, hidden)  -- in any order
```

A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (aka `LEFT JOIN`), per se, is not the villain.  Having a subquery in it may be the real villain.  Several things can be done with such, but I am not sure any cure applies to your case:

- Get rid of `LEFT`.  But this would lose some rows if they are missing from `ads_rating`.  Without `LEFT`, the subquery would probably be performed *first* instead of repeatedly.  (If this is valid, try it first.)
- Move the subquery into the `SELECT`.  But there are two columns being provided, so it is unlikely to be practical.
- Use `WITH`.  But this requires version 8.0.  What version are you using?
- `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` for the subquery, then use it in place of the subquery.  (This may be the best choice.)

Comment: Great! I´m using MariaDB 10.2, SO how do I create the composite INDEX? INDEX(sellfast, subcat_id, recycle_bin, hidden)

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ads ADD INDEX(sellfast, subcat_id, recycle_bin, hidden);`